# HttpURLConnection method setDoOutput() always return false after setting true too

Tags: android, file-upload, httpurlconnection

I want to make a "PUT" request for uploading File to the Server.
For this i am using HttpURLConnection but it is not working.I have given the code below

```
public static String sendFileToServer(String filePath, String targetUrl)
{
    URL url =  new URL(targetUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput( true );
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
    connection.setRequestMethod( "PUT" );
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

}
```

this is my code, but connection method i get is

```
doOutput = false
```

and

```
method = {String@5347} "GET"
```

I have tried to solve but it doesn't work anyway. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Follow this exsample:

```
 private void openConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    if (request.getHttpBody() != null) {
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
    }
    connection.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());
    Map<String, String> map = request.getHeaders();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();

        Logger.i("prepare headers with key = " + key + "  value = " + value);
        connection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    connection.setReadTimeout((int) mReadTimeout);
    connection.setConnectTimeout((int) mConnectionTimeout);
    if (connection.getDoOutput()) {
        connection.connect();
    }
}
```

HttpRequest  - custom wrapper class with headers.

Comment: HttpRequest Methods are not available

Comment: HttpRequest - custom wrapper class with headers.